# capturing the emulator screen(android):

Tags: android, emulation

my app should have a button say start/stop upon click it should capture the emulator screen including mouse movements and what's on the screen
and when stopped, it will stop capturing the screen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get screen captures from an Android emulator using the [`ddms` tool that comes with the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html).

[image: Click for full size]

[image: Click for full size]

I am not aware of any standard Android APIs for screen capture.  All of the screen capture applications I have seen on the Android Market require a rooted device, so I'm fairly sure there's no easy way to do this within your application.

Comment: hi thanks i know that but how can i use that facility through my code

Comment: I'm not quite clear why you want to do this through code? Will it not cause problems when the app is run on a phone?

Comment: I think he wants to develop a capture module to...would be interessting to have it on android :)

Comment: right now i want to try this app on my emulator but later i need to deploy it on a real device..i want to know is their any api's to capture screen and/or record the screen...